# ocaml-top does not compile past (pattern matching) Warning 8

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, warnings

With ocaml-top 1.1.5 and ocaml 4.02.3 on macOS High Sierra:

When compiling a file where a function triggers a (pattern matching) Warning 8, the warning is displayed in red (in the Windows ocaml-top version I usually use it would be yellow) ; the function itself seems to compile and gives a type, but functions below it in the file cannot be compiled (as if the Warning was an actual compilation error).

How can I compile past that? My missing cases are obviously intentional.

EDIT: with no ocaml-top specific answer, I'm just completing all my pattern matchings with `_-> failwith "blabla"`   type statements. Should I use something else than ocaml-top, anything not too hard to install on macOS for somebody who has not idea how package dependency and so on work?

Comment: maybe you can disable warning by defining your function with `[@warning "-8"]`.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the difference in the two environments is in the compiler options. Warnings (by definition) don't terminate compilation. But each warning (by number) can be made fatal with the `-w` option like this:

```
ocamlc -w @8  ...
```

If you can find this setting you can remove it to get the default treatment for warning 8.

Compiler options are described in [Section 8.2](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.05/comp.html#sec266) of the OCaml manual.

As @vonaka says, you can also use attributes in the source to turn off a warning for just one function like this:

```
let [@warning "-8"] myfun x =
    match x with None -> 18
```

Attributes are described in [Section 7.18](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.05/extn.html#sec246) of the OCaml manual. Built-in attributes like `[@warning ...]` are described in section 7.18.1.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the ocaml-top window gives no compiling options, and trying: `let [@warning "-8"] myfun x =2*x;;` gives `Error: Syntax error: attributes not expected.`

Comment: I haven't used ocaml-top but it's possible that both of these are controlled by configuration options of ocaml-top. You could be working with default settings that emphasize safety (treat warnings as errors) and simplicity (don't support attributes).